# How to manually send error 504 with RxJS (for local mock)?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to manually send error 504 (or any other code) using RxJS?

Want to locally test error handling.

Comment: Are you talking about a service using the `HttpClient`? Read https://angular.io/guide/http-test-requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two imports are needed:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

We use [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse) to prepare our error.
Then we simply throw an Error passing our body.

Since RxJS 7, it's recommended to use a factory function as a parameter inside our [throwError function](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError), so here is the final result:

```
  const customError = new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: 'Custom 504 error occured',
        status: 504,
        statusText: 'Sample 504 status text',
    });
    throwError(() => customError).subscribe();
```